# Cannot authenticate user using mobile services on windows phone 8.1

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a universal store app and using the following code to authenticate user with facebook

```
client.login("facebook").done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

this works fine on windows 8.1, but on windows phone 8.1 gives error, and shows unexpected failure.

The error object in console is as shown below

```
The method Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceMap.getValue has been deprecated. GetValue(string) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows Phone 'OSVersion' (TBD). Instead, use GetValue(string, ResourceContext).
Unexpected failure.
{
  [functions]: ,
  __proto__: { },
  exception: {
     [functions]: ,
     __proto__: { },
     description: "Not implemented",
     message: "Not implemented",
     name: "WinRTError",
     number: -2147467263,
     stack: "WinRTError: Not implemented
     at login (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:2224:17)
     at loginWithLoginControl (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:1516:13)
     at loginWithProvider (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:1358:17)
     at login (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:1265:17)
     at Anonymous function (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:322:17)
     at Anonymous function (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:2063:25)
     at Promise_ctor (ms-appx://microsoft.phone.winjs.2.1/js/base.js:2038:17)
     at Anonymous function (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/MobileServices.js:2046:17)
     at Anonymous function (ms-appx://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/js/default.js:15:13)"
  },
  message: "Unexpected failure."
}
```

I am using JavaScript backend on my azure service and my dashboard is logging my authentication attempts as http server error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the Mobile Service SDK are you using?

Comment: 1.2.2 http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WinJS/